# Is it really true that slow-roll inflation is incompatible with string theory?

Tags: string-theory, cosmology, cosmological-inflation

In [this blog post](http://motls.blogspot.com/2012/08/alan-guth-and-inflation.html), Motl claimed that slow-roll inflation is incompatible with string theory. Is that really true, and why do people think so?

Comment: Did you see the papers dealing with the issue Lumo linked to in the comments below the blog post?